# Why i am getting following error in some circumstances

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting following error message, when i tried below codes. Is it a bug in Selenium?

> Sep 19, 2014 10:01:09 PM
>   org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog destroyHarder
>   INFO: Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully (v2).
>   org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog@15ae139

Scenario 1:

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
driver.navigate().to("http://www.yahoo.com");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
driver.quit();
```

Scenario 2:

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
driver.navigate().to("http://www.yahoo.com");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
driver.quit();
```

Comment: What version of Selenium + Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Selenium API](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html):

> navigate()
>
> An abstraction allowing the driver to access the **browser's history** and
>   to navigate to a given URL.

(emphasis is mine) So unless you somehow populate the history first, your code should fail all the time.